# Jsoncpp - very simple test crashes when Json::reader goes ot of scope

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I have downloaded and installed the jsoncpp library. I then try to use the library in my own application:

```
#include <json/json.h>

void parseJson() {
   Json::Reader reader;
} 

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   parseJson();
   exit(0);
}
```

The program compiles and links fine, but it crashes with SIGSEGV when running. The gdb  backtrace looks like this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003a560b7672 in __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00000000004031e9 in std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose (this=0xffffffffffffffe9, __a=@0x7fffbfe60e57)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:232
#2  0x0000000000403236 in ~basic_string (this=0x7fffbfe60fb0)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:478
#3  0x00000000004038d4 in ~Reader (this=0x7fffbfe60eb0) at /private/joaho/Parser/opm-parser/external/json/json-cpp/include/json/reader.h:23
#4  0x0000000000402990 in parseJson () at /private/joaho/Parser/opm-parser/opm/parser/eclipse/ExternalTests/ExternalTests.cpp:51
#5  0x00000000004029ab in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffbfe610c8)
at /home/user/Parser/opm-parser/opm/parser/eclipse/ExternalTests/ExternalTests.cpp:56
```

I.e. to me it seems to crash in the destructor. As far as I can tell the Json::Reader does not have it's own dstructor, so this must be a default destructor. As you can see I am running a quite old version of g++ - could that be the problem?

Comment: When compiled with GCC version 4.8.1 on Debian/Sid (so libjsoncpp-dev `0.6.0~rc2-3`) as `g++-4.8 -g -Wall -I/usr/include/jsoncpp/ esjson.cc -ljsoncpp -o esjson`  your program is compiled without warnings, and does not crash when running.

Comment: I had this exact problem in VS2013. It came from not linking to the debug version of the library when doing a debug build.

Comment: I have seen this issue in a bit of a spaghetti code project I have that statically links in webrtc (which links in jsoncpp) and also includes jsoncpp dynamically through another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented:

> When compiled with GCC version 4.8.1 on Debian/Sid (so libjsoncpp-dev `0.6.0~rc2-3`) as `g++-4.8 -g -Wall -I/usr/include/jsoncpp/ esjson.cc -ljsoncpp -o esjson`  your program is compiled without warnings, and does not crash when running.

And GCC 4.1.2 is really old ([febr. 2007](http://gcc.gnu.org/news.html) !) and is not supported anymore,  and not very well C++ standard conforming (GCC, now at version 4.8.1, has made huge progress on C++ standard conformance since 4.1).

So I am not sure GCC 4.1. is faulty, but I won't be surprised it is: it had bad C++ reputation, and both the C++ standard and the GCC compiler have been improved a lot since that. Upgrading your GCC is worth the effort, both for better support of C++ and for improved diagnostics and optimizations.

<sup>So I suggest you to use a newer GCC; if you don't have root access, consider compiling its from its source tarball; build it outside of the source tree with e.g. `../gcc-4.8.1/configure --program-suffix=-4.8 --prefix=$HOME/pub` then `make` then `make install` - after having installed its dependencies</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the effort; I guess I will blame the old gcc compiler. The reason I am slightly reluctant to install a newer compiler is that I am in a veeery conservative corporate environment, and the applications I write must work on the runtime (i.e. gcc-4.1.2) distributed throughout the organisation. My json needs are quite simple, so maybe I will try to find another (pure C?) library.

Comment: There are other good reasons to advocate, within your corporation, the use of a newer GCC compiler: better standard conformance, better optimizations, better diagnostics.... Using GCC 4.1 for any kind of C++ programming is asking for deep trouble. (Most compiler bugs are *harder to find* than this one).